# CAML Query based on Created and Modified columns in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query

I want to  get all the items that are created or modified from the last 4 hours from a SharePoint  Online list using CSOM.
 I am using the below CAML query but i am not getting the items

```
DateTime startdate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-4);
DateTime enddate = DateTime.Now;

 var finalquery = "<View><Query><Where><Or><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + startdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + enddate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + "</Value></Leq></And><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + startdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + enddate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + "</Value></Leq></And></Or></Where></Query></View>";
```

I am converting the dates to `.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")` while passing to CAML query
And my CAML Query is as below while debugging .

```
<View><Query><Where><Or><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2018-05-01T11:12:56Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2018-05-01T15:17:54Z</Value></Leq></And><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2018-05-01T11:12:56Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2018-05-01T15:17:54Z</Value></Leq></And></Or></Where></Query></View>
```

But all the items are created and modified recently
[image]

Can any one help me on this please.

Comment: Which type of help you want?

Comment: I want the know what is the error in the query..

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your tines backward or forward a few hours as a test. SharePoint Online web services use UTC internally. London time. I had some issues with JavaScript created dates and the REST API awhile back. I'll see if I can find my notes...

Comment: After adjusting  the time  to 8 hours, the query is working fine. But i want to know why it is not working for 4 hours. Where to check the Time settings, both the Site and Azure function are in US time

Comment: Internally SharePoint Online uses GMT / Universal Time (UTC) (same time as London). The displayed times (what displays in pages) are adjusted at the Tenant level, at the site level ( Site Administration, Regional settings ) and/or at the user level ( My Account, Settings, Language and time zone )  Almost all system level work is GMT/UTC. (REST API, search, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Without having really tried the query it looks valid.

But what are you using it for? Depending on the usage you may need to remove `<View>` and `<Query>` (and the corresponding closing tags)

Answer (score 0):

As Per Jakobsen said , your query looks valid , i made a quick test on a console application to test and works, it would be more helpful if you added your full function to your question so we can help you determine what went wrong, but i'm adding the test sample below for your reference.

```
   string siteUrl = "https://server/sites/xyz";
   ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
   List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("testv");
   CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
   camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Or><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2018-05-01T11:12:56Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2018-05-01T15:17:54Z</Value></Leq></And><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2018-05-01T11:12:56Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2018-05-01T15:17:54Z</Value></Leq></And></Or></Where></Query></View>";

   ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
   clientContext.Load(collListItem);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I am using   my query in azure function